# Prove that for any small enough translation of a simplex either the new simplex has a vertex of the old simplex or viceversa

Tags: geometry, convex-geometry

Consider a $n$ dimensional simplex. Prove (or disprove) that a small enough translation of it in any direction produces a simplex which either has a vertex of the old simplex, either the new simplex has a vertex in the old simplex.

---

This property seems interesting and is obvious for the two dimensional case, as seen in the picture: [image]

Here, in any direction one would move the triangle, one of the vertices would be in the interior of the new triangle, or the new triangle would have a vertex in the old one. How can this be properly proved in the general case?

---

To formalize the claim, let $V_k$ be a vertex of the simplex $\mathcal{S}$ and denote $\Omega_k = \mathcal{B}(V_k,\epsilon) \cap \mathcal{S}$.

Then we basically claim that
$$ \left( \bigcup_{k=1}^{n+1} \{x - V_k | x \in \Omega_k\} \right) \cup \left( \bigcup_{k=1}^{n+1} \{-x + V_k | x \in \Omega_k\} \right) = \mathcal{B}(0,\epsilon)$$

---

### Edit

It seems that in general

$$ \left( \bigcup_{k=1}^{n+1} \{x - V_k | x \in \Omega_k\} \right) \cup \left( \bigcup_{k=1}^{n+1} \{-x + V_k | x \in \Omega_k\} \right) \subseteq \mathcal{B}(0,\epsilon)$$ Let

$$ \Lambda = \left( \bigcup_{k=1}^{n+1} \{x - V_k | x \in \Omega_k\} \right) \cup \left( \bigcup_{k=1}^{n+1} \{-x + V_k | x \in \Omega_k\} \right) $$ then can we estimate
$$ \frac{\text{vol}(\Lambda)}{\text{vol}(\mathcal{B}(0,\epsilon))}$$

Comment: I think the problem with this constuction is regular tetrahedrons on their own don't fill euclidean space. For instance a box does by connecting a box to each face of the previous box like a grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not true in three dimensions. Take a regular tetrahedron with unit sides, resting on the $(x,y)-$plane with one vertex on the positive $x$-axis and one vertex on the positive $z$-axis. Now raise it a distance $\epsilon$, and translate it along the $x$-axis by a distance $\epsilon$.

Comment: the vertices of the initial simplex are: $[000],[100],[010],[001]$. Translate by $z$ to obtain the vertices $[0,0,e], [1,0,e], [0,1,e], [0,0,1+e]$. Translate by x to obtain $[e,0,e], [1+e,0,e], [e,1,e], [e,0,1+e]$. Why is not $[e,0,e]$ in the initial simplex?

Comment: I should have said a _regular_ tetrahedron (which your simplex is not). Edited to make this clear.

Comment: I guess you are right ... Is there though a measure of how wrong this is ? ... I will edit the question ...